# Colors in Vim via gnome terminal are not the same with gVim

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, vim, gvim

why is it that the colors when using the color scheme 'blackboard' via Vim in gnome terminal is not the same as when I use the same theme in gVim?
i.e. the background is black while on gVim it's blue and the function names are not colroed etc. Only a few parts of teh code are colored.

Here's my .vimrc

```
filetype plugin indent on
set number
let &t_Co=256
```

Also on my Profile Preferences > Colors tab, I got:
Bulit-in Schemes: Green on Black
Built-in schemes: XTerm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) - very good at matching colourschemes (in linux at least - in OSX the default terminal does not have enough colours)

Fairly simple to set up - just configure how many colours are usable by your terminal and put the needed information in your .vimrc

Answer (score 3):

Vim running in a terminal emulator uses so-called ANSI codes to display color. gVim doesn't relay on terminal emulation, and can use any RGB color it likes.

In the color scheme declaration that's guifg & guibg entries for gVim, and ctermfg & ctermbg entries for terminal emulators. See

```
:help syntax
```

for more details about differences between syntax highlighting between vim working inside a terminal emulator and as a standalone GUI program.

Comment: So is there a solution for it?

Comment: Sure. Edit either the mapping from ANSI colors to RGB in your terminal emulator to match the colors that gVim uses, or edit the definition of the color scheme for gVim to match RGB values that your terminal emulator uses.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this vim tips wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_GUI_color_settings_in_a_terminal) were two solutions for making consistent colorschemes between terminals and GUI are discussed.